# Swift changing UINavigationBar's shadow affects its UIBarButtonItem when appearance change

Tags: swift, uikit, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem, uinavigationbarappearance

I'm trying to update the UINavigationBar's shadow like this

```swift
func setCustomShadow() {
    self.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
    self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.1
    self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 5)
    self.layer.shadowRadius = 0.25
        
    self.layer.masksToBounds = false
}
```

it works fine when you scroll down like this
[image]

But the issue will occur when it get's back on top, the shadow will apply on the UIBarButtonItem like this
[image]

I want its current behavior, I just want to prevent the shadow on my UIBarButtonItem.

The question is, How can I prevent it from occurring on the UIBarButtonItem?

EDIT: I tried using UINavigationBarAppearance and update the `shadowImage` like this

```swift
let appearance1 = UINavigationBarAppearance()
appearance1.shadowImage = UIImage(named: "custom_shadow_image")

compactAppearance = nil
standardAppearance = appearance1
scrollEdgeAppearance = nil
```

with this method, I get a desired result on navigation bar's white appearance like this
[image]

but I'm still getting an issue on it's transparent appearance, it still displaying the `shadowImage` like this

[image]

I tried playing with compactAppearance, standardAppearance and scrollEdgeAppearance but still didn't get the desired output.

I don't want the `shadowImage` to be displayed on transparent appearance of the navigation bar, how can I do that?

Comment: Don't mess with the layer at all. `UINavigationBar` provides a direct API for setting up its appearance. Look at the `standardAppearance` and related properties of `UINavigationBar`.

Comment: @HangarRash I'm also trying to work with appearance, but it seems like I can't find a way to change the shadowOpacity, shadowOffset and shadowRadius with UINavigationBarAppearance, do you have any suggestion I can use to change those component using UINavigationBarAppearance?

Comment: It does seem that UIBarAppearance only supports `shadowColor`. Perhaps you'll need to use `shadowImage` to get the desired shadow.

Comment: @HangarRash does swift can generate a UIImage with that desired configuration, or do I need to create my own image asset, or if both can do, what is better or much more better practice?

Comment: @HangarRash I edited the question and add a workaround for UIBarAppearance's `shadowImage`, but I encountered another problem using that method.

Comment: If you set `scrollEdgeAppearance` to `nil` then it will use `standardAppearance`. So if you don't want the two to have the same shadow then each needs its own appearance configured as desired.

Comment: @HangarRash I also tried playing with it, I create a new appearance and set it's image into `UIImage()` like this `appearance2.shadowImage = UIImage()` and set it on `scrollEdgeAppearance` but It didn't lose it's `shsdowImage` instead it add white background on my navigation bar that supposed to be transparent